# Small factors of $(2^{1642811}-1)\cdot 10^{494536}+2^{1642810}-1$

Tags: number-theory

Consider primes of the form:

$3371+327888\cdot s$, for s nonnegative.

The first three are: $3371$, $331259$ and $1642811$.

$(2^{3371}-1)\cdot 10^{1015}+2^{3370}-1$, is probable prime, where $1015$ is the number of decimal digits of $2^{3370}-1$.

$(2^{331259}-1)\cdot 10^{99719}+2^{331258}-1$, is probable prime, where $99179$ is the number of decimal digits of $2^{331258}-1$.

So I tried to plug in in the formula the third prime: $1642811$.

$(2^{1642811}-1)\cdot 10^{494536}+2^{1642810}-1=A$

The number A is not prime. It is divisible by $91739407$, but it has no other factor below $10^9$.

Can we conclude that there are no small smactors other than $91739407$, and what the chance to find another factor?
What the chance that the number is a semi-prime?

I found another factor in a blink of an eye with Siqs. I dont know why Siqs was so quick to find a 15 digit factor. Maybe an error?

$P15 = 227131270328969$ which divides A, no maybe it does not divide A, maybe there is some issue with Siqs

The three primes $3371$, $331259$ and $1642811$ have the form $72\cdot s-13$ and also of the form $59+23\cdot s$

Comment: If a small factor is defined as a factor $<10^9$, then your finding that there are no other factors $<10^9$ does indeed show that there are no other small factors

Comment: @Peter why Siqs in an instant could find another 15-digits factor of A?

Comment: @Peter I found an error there is some issue with siqs it does P15 does not divide A

Comment: siqs is a quadratic sieve. This number is far too large for this method. $P15\nmid A$

Comment: The best chance for another factor is probably the p-1-method since ECM is extremely time consuming for such a large number. Chances for the cofactor to be prime are very low, hence $A$ is almost certain not semiprime.

Comment: For those wondering about this particular number. It is a so-called "Enzo-Creti-number" emerging by concattenating two Mersenne numbers $M(n)$ and $M(n-1)$ in base $10$, I and Enzo Creti invented the notation "$ec(n)$"  for such a number.

Comment: No further prime factor upto $10^{11}$. Currently running p-1-method

Comment: @Peter \still chances to be prime are small?

Comment: About $1:50\ 000$

Comment: @Peter ok thanks

Comment: @Peter with the p-1 method can you find factors 30-digits long?

Comment: Only with much luck ! I think we better try ECM although it will take very long.

Comment: Do you have PFGW to test the cofactor for primality ?

Comment: @Peter no it doesn't work

Comment: Martin Hopf proved the cofactor composite and hence showed that $A$ is not a semiprime. The computation took about $8\frac{1}{2}$ hours.

Answer (score 2):

After a 'quick' primality test with PFGW the compositeness of $\large \frac {A}{91739407}$ is proven!

```
((2^1642811-1)*10^494536+2^1642810-1)/91739407 is composite: RES64: [A3A230C5E98B5040] (30348.4725s+0.1158s)
```

About 8 hours and 30 minutes to find out for sure.